# How can I eliminate a temporary vector when reading in a 2D vector?

Tags: vector, rust

I have this code for reading in a 2D vector. Is there a way to eliminate the need for `temp_vec`?

```
let mut vec_size: usize = 3;
let mut vec = vec![vec![0; vec_size]; vec_size];   
for i in 0..vec_size{
    input = String::new();
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).expect("Failed to read");
    let temp_vec: Vec<i32> = input
             .split_whitespace()
             .map(|s| s.parse().unwrap())
             .collect();
    for j in 0..temp_vec.len(){
        vec[i][j] = temp_vec[j];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map the lines of standard input as the rows, then map the numbers in each row as columns.

```
use std::io;
use std::io::prelude::*;

const SIZE: usize = 3;

fn main() {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let vec: Vec<Vec<i32>> = stdin.lock()
        .lines()
        .take(SIZE)
        .map(|line| {
            let line = line.expect("Unable to read line");
            line.split_whitespace()
                .take(SIZE)
                .map(|s| s.parse().expect("Enable to parse number"))
                .collect()
        })
        .collect();

    println!("{:?}", vec);
}
```

Or if you don't care to panic:

```
use std::io;
use std::io::prelude::*;
use std::error::Error;

const SIZE: usize = 3;

fn main() {
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    let vec: Result<Vec<Vec<i32>>, _> = stdin.lock()
        .lines()
        .take(SIZE)
        .map(|line| {
            line.map_err(|e| Box::new(e) as Box<Error>)
                .and_then(|line| {
                    line.split_whitespace()
                        .take(SIZE)
                        .map(|s| s.parse().map_err(|e| Box::new(e) as Box<Error>))
                        .collect()
                })
        })
        .collect();

    println!("{:?}", vec);
}
```

---

Addressing concerns from a comment:

> Your code makes 2n+1 allocations (that's important if somebody's looking for performance

It's unclear what `N` is here, but there should be a maximum of 3 vectors allocated and 3 items in each vector. The `take` adapter will override the `size_hint` to put a maximum of `3` and then `collect` will use that hint when constructing each `Vec`.

> Using nested `Vec`s for matrices is an antipattern.

Absolutely, but that was what the original code did.

> You "break" stdin – you can't reliably use it after calling `lock().lines()`

I'm not sure what you mean here. I am able to add `stdin.read(&mut[0,0,0]).expect("Unable to read more")` after the chunk of code that defines `let vec`, showing that it can be used.

If there was a problem with not being able to use stdin, you could fix it by scoping the lock to a block that ends earlier.

Comment: Thanks!, seems you're answering all my rust related questions, maybe they should change the site to Shepmaster exchange :)

Comment: @KDN nah; I just spend too much time here. There are plenty of people that could make better answers than I can, but they are off doing other things. And there's lots of areas where I couldn't even begin to provide a useful answer!

Answer (score 3):

I you remove the `collect()` call, you end up with an iterator, which you can `enumerate()` and just pass to the for loop:

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let vec_size: usize = 3;
    let mut vec = vec![vec![0; vec_size]; vec_size];   
    let mut input = String::new();
    for i in 0..vec_size {
        input.clear();
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).expect("Failed to read");
        let numbers = input
            .split_whitespace()
            .map(|s| s.parse().unwrap());
        for (j, x) in numbers.enumerate() {
            vec[i][j] = x;
        }
    }
}
```

This code also calls `clear()` to clear the input buffer instead of assigning new string, so it makes just one additional allocation (you may benefit from it if you're reading a lot of small matrices).

(sidenote about your code: it's better to use `.iter().enumerate()` than iterate on vectors indices, if you can)

---

When writing this answer I've misread the original question thinking that there was a stack-allocated matrix:

```
const VEC_SIZE: usize = 3;
let mut vec = [[0; VEC_SIZE]; VEC_SIZE];
```

If that was the case, I would recommend my solution, but since it's a `Vec<Vec<i32>>`, I'd recommend @Shepmaster's one, as it's more idiomatic.